# Patch entity with delta

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have an override that patches an entity.

```
protected override Books PatchEntity(int key, Delta<Books> patch)
{
    var Book = db.books.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID== key);
    if (Book == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    patch.Patch(Book);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Book ;
}
```

What I need to do is intercept it so I can put a business rule, for example : if title has certain words, then reject.

How do I capture the message body that is being sent by the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
patch.GetEntity().BookName
```